# Sort upcoming birthdays based on current date

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, date, datetime

I have the following table of people and their birthdays:

```
name        birthday
----------------------
yannis      1979-06-29
natalia     1980-08-19
kostas      1983-10-27    
christos    1979-07-22
kosmas      1978-04-28
```

and I have no idea how to sort the names on how closer the birthday is to today. So for NOW() = 2011-09-08 the sorted result should be:

```
kostas      1983-10-27
kosmas      1978-04-28
yannis      1979-06-29
christos    1979-07-22
natalia     1980-08-19
```

I'm looking for a quick hack, don't really care for performance (pet project - table will hold less than 1000 records), but of course every suggestion will be extremely appreciated.

Comment: @ajreal Her birthday is in August, so she'll have to wait the longest for her party :)

Comment: OK so you want *upcoming* birthdays sorted by the one closest to today?

Comment: @Salman Yes :) Edited the title, hope it's clearer now

Comment: I edited my answer after you accepted. Original answer had problems with leap years.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one way:

- Calculate **current year** - **year of birth**
- Add the resulting number of years to the **date of birth**
- You now have the birthday this year, if this date has passed then add one more year
- Sort the results by that date

```sql
SELECT
    name,
    birthday,
    birthday + INTERVAL (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(birthday))     YEAR AS currbirthday,
    birthday + INTERVAL (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(birthday)) + 1 YEAR AS nextbirthday
FROM birthdays
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN currbirthday >= CURRENT_DATE THEN currbirthday
    ELSE nextbirthday
END
```

Notes:

- Today's birthdays appears first regardless of current time
- February 29 birthday is treated equal to February 28 birthday for common years e.g.

  - On Jan/1/2019 both Feb 28 and Feb 29 birthdays (2019) are sorted equal
  - On Mar/1/2019 Feb 28 and Feb 29 birthdays (2020) are sorted as expected

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a5c0/1)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT name
     , birthday
FROM TableX
ORDER BY DAYOFYEAR(birthday) < DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())
       , DAYOFYEAR(birthday)
```

---

No, the above may produce error results, due to years with 366 days. This is correct:

```
SELECT name
     , birthday
FROM
  ( SELECT name
         , birthday
         , MONTH(birthday) AS m
         , DAY(birthday) As d
    FROM TableX
  ) AS tmp
ORDER BY (m,d) < ( MONTH(CURDATE()), DAY(CURDATE()) )
       , m
       , d
```

---

If your table grows to more than a few thousands records, it will be real slow. If you want a fast query, add fields with the month and day and have an index on `(bmonth,bday)` or add them as one field, either Char (`08-17` or `0817` for 17-Aug) or Int (`817` for 17-Aug) and an index on that field.

Comment: Is there any example of rejection for the first query?

Comment: @Hafez What do you mean with "rejection"?

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be rather fast, no problems with leap years:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `people` 
ORDER BY CONCAT(SUBSTR(`birthday`,6) < SUBSTR(CURDATE(),6), SUBSTR(`birthday`,6))
```

Все гениальное -- просто! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty, but works

```
SELECT * 
,CASE WHEN BirthdayThisYear>=NOW() THEN BirthdayThisYear ELSE BirthdayThisYear + INTERVAL 1 YEAR END AS NextBirthday
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    ,birthday - INTERVAL YEAR(birthday) YEAR + INTERVAL YEAR(NOW()) YEAR AS BirthdayThisYear
    FROM bd
) AS bdv
ORDER BY NextBirthday
```

Answer (score 0):

i would try it like this (but this isn't tested):

```
SELECT
  name,
  birthday
FROM
  birthdays
ORDER BY
  ABS( DAYOFYEAR(birthday) - (DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) ) ASC
```

**EDIT:**
changed ordering from `DESC` to `ASC` because you want to get the farthest first, not the closest.

Comment: I dont think this works correctly. An user who had birthday yesterday, would show somewhere close to the top, and I dont think this is what we want.