# Sorting mysql upcoming birthdays of users

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL query to sort upcoming birthdays based on current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343807/mysql-query-to-sort-upcoming-birthdays-based-on-current-date)

I have a MYSQL code like:

```
$friends=mysql_query("SELECT id,friend_id,f_name,
DATE_FORMAT(f_birthday,'%d %b')
AS f_birthday from friends where id='$id' 
ORDER BY MONTH(f_birthday), DAYOFMONTH(f_birthday)");
```

with this code block i can sort the user's birtdays with months and days starting from January first. But i can not sort them according to the upcoming birthdays. Searched for hours and found many solutions on stackoverflow but could not succeed. I really need help.
Thanks.

**EDIT**

EXAMPLE OF MYSQL TABLE:

> ```
>        id         friend_id        f_name      f_birthday
> 100001403795149 542542215       Mıchael        1984-10-01
> 100001403795149 557277949       MARY           1966-11-30
> 100001403795149 100002251590924 John           1985-07-05
> 100001403795149 100002534859304 Lucas          1977-09-15
> ```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,friend_id,f_name,
DATE_FORMAT(f_birthday,'%d %b')
AS f_birthday from friends where id='$id' and f_birthday >=now()
ORDER BY MONTH(f_birthday), DAYOFMONTH(f_birthday) asc
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working. _MySQL returned an empty result_

Comment: This query will give you all birtdays which will fall today or in future in ascending order.So pls check in your table are there any records whoses birthday >=today

Comment: I have edited my question showing a few records of the database table.

Comment: solved the problem by another question. Thanks. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343807/mysql-query-to-sort-upcoming-birthdays-based-on-current-date]