# Join a View with a Procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a **View** called `upcoming_birthday` which returns a list of people having birthday on the next 7 days (special thanks: [Upcoming Birthday based on Current Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343807/mysql-query-to-sort-upcoming-birthdays-based-on-current-date]) and [Upcoming Birthdays for this week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747853/mysql-select-upcoming-birthdays)).

I have a **Procedure** that takes as input the ID of a company and outputs every customer linked to said company. By `link` I mean "has a relation with". The origin of those links are `sign up by` or `purchased at` (*ie customers can be signed up by a company A and, after purchasing something at company B, they'll have a link with companies A and B*).

Now I'd like to join those two results. Something like:

```
SELECT a.* FROM upcoming_birthday AS b INNER JOIN (CALL proc_account_link_company(2)) AS a ON b.id = a.id
```

Is it doable?

Comment: I have a question, What is mean of `a` in `SELECT a.* FROM upcoming_brithday` ? Is `a` a column from the table of `upcoming_birthday` ? If yes, so why you write `a` when you write `*` ?

Comment: `a` is the alias of the "second table" (in this case procedure). The meaning is like `SELECT a.* FROM table1 b INNER JOIN table2 a ON b.id = a.id` in such a way that I only care for all columns at **table2** and I don't want any columns from **table1**.

Comment: Aha, I thought `,` is between `a` and `*`, Then `a` is a alias name of `CALL proc_account_link_company(2)`, right ?

Comment: I don't think you can `JOIN` results of a procedure. Your procedure can write to a temporary/intermediate table instead. That table can be joined with upcoming_birthday table